# Как вынести переменную из функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, aiogram

Начал изучать python с практики и писать бота для телеграма. Вот в чём проблема:
Есть функция

```
    def check_user_status(self, user_id, status):
        with self.connection:
            sql = "SELECT `status` FROM `userinfo` WHERE `user_id` = ?"
            rs = self.cursor.execute(sql, (user_id, )).fetchone()
            user_status = rs[0] if rs else None
            return user_status == status
```

Насколько я понял, она возвращает в переменную `status` значение взятое из ДБ. В файле с ботом у меня запрашивается переменная `status`, но выходит ошибка: `module 'sqlcfg' has no attribute 'status'`. sqlcg - это если что файл с инструкциями к управлению ДБ. Как я понимаю, основной файл не видит переменную `status`, потому что она в функции. Мне нужно чтобы он её видел. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Непонятная функция. У неё и в параметрах вызова есть `status` и как `global` ещё `status` описан. Это какая-то каша. И при этом функция в переменную `status` ничего не записывает, поэтому непонятно, зачем ей `global status` вообще.

Comment: global status это я не туда написал, его нету в исходном коде и что нужно дописать, чтобы в status функция записывала значение?

Comment: Уже решил проблему, убрал из параметров вызова status, сделал его глобальным и приравнял к значению user_status. Отчасти вы мне помогли, отметил бы ваше решение, как верное, если бы вы его написали) Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже решил проблему, убрал из параметров вызова status, сделал его глобальным и приравнял к значению user_status, рабочий код прилагаю:

```
    def check_user_status(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            global status
            sql = "SELECT `status` FROM `userinfo` WHERE `user_id` = ?"
            rs = self.cursor.execute(sql, (user_id, )).fetchone()
            user_status = rs[0] if rs else None
            status = user_status
            return bool(status)
```